# Mobile product page image gallery - what should be the default zoom state?

Tags: image, lightbox, photos

For example, there is product page on mobile website or app that looks like this:

[image]

User taps on image to zoom it in - what should happen? Should it fit into viewport, like this:

[image]

Or should it fill viewport, like this:

[image]

And if it fills viewport - how left/right swipe should work? Should it open just one image or the whole gallery?

Or maybe something else should happen?

I downloaded a few shopping mobile apps and they're very inconsistent. Please share your thoughts or studies regarding the matter.

Answer (score 1):

I can share my thoughts but do not have any studies.

In your first suggestion the picture is not really larger then the preview on the product page. The second suggestion shows the picture larger but only with a tiny cut out.

I think the first suggestion is the one to go for. The user should then have the possibility to zoom in and out at will and can therefore decide which part of the image is most interesting to him. If you go this way, you could provide small thumbnails below the picture instead of just bullets to indicate that there are more pictures. This gives the user even more control over the process of looking at the pictures he wants to. 
swipe should always bring the user to the next picture.